# Word for "An expression or saying one uses so much that it comes to define them"

Tags: meaning

I am searching for an (English) word or terse expression that denotes something a person habitually says (in appropriate contexts--not verbal twitches) so often that they come to be defined as that expression. Viz.:

> Oh, you sound just like X! That's his [characteristically habitually used expression]

or

> He was a [characteristically habitually used expression] kind of man. Full of everything that expression implies.

Comment: Please clarify "fine" and "vim and verge". It seems to me that you've accidentally mistyped a couple of words.

Comment: Idiomatically, *Oh, you sound just like X! That's his **trademark*** is common.

Answer (score 2):

[**Catchphrase**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catchphrase) would fit the first sentence.

I don't see how the word you ask for in the first sentence would fit the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**Shtick**

> one's special trait, interest, or activity : BAG

*He's alive and well and now doing his shtick out in Hollywood.*
— Robert Daley

[Merriam-Webster]